# React Navigation V5 Conditional Navigator screens based on async storage value

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using the following [guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) for react navigation V5

I have add a a welcome screen and home screen to a stack navigator
and I have a token in [Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) to check the value of the token

if the token is true navigator should render home
and if its null it will render the welcome screen

now as async storage as asynchronous welcomeScreen is rendered
at every launch of the app.

```html
let check = null
getData = async () => {
try {
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@firstLaunch')
if(value !== null) {
check === value
}
} catch(e) {
// error reading value
}
}

return (
<Stack.Navigator>
{check === null ? (
// No token found, render welcome screen
<Stack.Screen
name="welcome"
component={WelcomeScreen}
}}
/>
) : (
// render HomeScreen
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
)}
</Stack.Navigator>
);

    let check = null
getData = async () => {
try {
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@firstLaunch')
if(value !== null) {
check === value
}
} catch(e) {
// error reading value
}
}

return (
<Stack.Navigator>
{check === null ? (
// No token found, render welcome screen
<Stack.Screen
name="welcome"
component={WelcomeScreen}
}}
/>
) : (
// render HomeScreen
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
)}
</Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something that uses an effect. The hook useEffect from react-native does just that.

Here you have an example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const WelcomeScreen = () => <View style={styles.view}><Text>Welcome Screen</Text></View>
const HomeScreen = () => <View style={styles.view}><Text>Home Screen</Text></View>

export default props => {

    const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null)
    const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            try {
                const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@firstLaunch')
                if(token !== null)
                    await setToken(token)
            } catch(e) {
            // error reading value
            }
            setLoaded(true)
        }

        getData()

        return () => null
    },[])

    // this is needed so you don't have that blink from Welcome to Home (When you have a token but it's not set yet in the state)
    if(!isLoaded)
        return null

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                { token === null
                    ? <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
                    : <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                }
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})
```